# Get a comma separated list of single quote string from string array?

Tags: arrays, string, postgresql, csv, aggregate-functions

I have this array:

```
ARRAY['this', 'is', 'my', 'string']
```

I would like to convert it into a string like this:

```
'this', 'is', 'my', 'string'
```

I tried:

```
array_to_string(ARRAY['this', 'is', 'my', 'string'], ',')
```

But instead of the desired output, I get this:

```
this, is, my, string
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using single quote characters for CSV format. Use double quotes or none. https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180

Answer (score 3):

Unnest the array, modify (add quotes to) all its elements and aggregate them into a string:

```
select string_agg(format('%L', elem), ',')
-- or
-- select string_agg(quote_literal(elem), ',')
from unnest(array['this', 'is', 'my', 'string']) elem

        string_agg         
---------------------------
 'this','is','my','string'
(1 row)
```

Comment: This is a proper answer.

Comment: maybe using `quote_literal` function instead `format` can be better - or the placeholder `%L` for `format` function can be used.

Comment: @PavelStehule - I aggree, the variant with `quote_literal()` is probably more elegant, thanks.

Comment: It gets a list with single quoted data and coma like 'a','b'.....

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to wrap the items of the array in single quotes yourself using character escaping, or by pre-processing the array to wrap the items in single quotes.
Try this

```
array_to_string(ARRAY['''this''','''is''','''my''','''string'''], ',')
```

Comment: (1) Standard SQL escapes single quotes by doubling them, not with backslashes. (2) Standard SQL's string concatenation operator is `||`. So I think you meant to say `'''' || array_to_string(ARRAY['this', 'is', 'my', 'string'], ''', ''') || ''''`.

Comment: @muistooshort is correct. If you change `\'` to `''` everywhere in your query, you will have a good solution.

Comment: I was trying to use PostgreSQL's escaping, but I did it wrong. Standard SQL escaping ends up nicer anyway, so I've switched it as you requested.